# Getting Json data from link

Tags: jquery, html, json, cordova, url

Good morning,

I have this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>READ JSON Example (AJAX)</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://phonegappro.esy.es/test/json.php",
         crossDomain: true,
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) {
             var result = $.parseJSON(result);
             $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                 $("#output").append("Title: " + field.title + " duration: " + field.duration + " Price:" + field.price + "<br/>");
             });
         }
     });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="output">

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

trying to get data from json. i have two json links.

1. http://www.bonar.si/api/restaurants.php
2. http://phonegappro.esy.es/test/json.php

The second one works, but the first one which i need, doesn't work. And they are almost the same. What seems to be a problem for the first one? maybe because its bigger file?

Thanks!

Comment: `almost` does't suit here. The response format should be `same`

Comment: Try using contentType as 'application/json' and dataType as 'json''

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The second server supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at console you get message

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bonar.si/api/restaurants.php.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

First of all ,open run window and type  `-> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` .Then execute code in new open Chrome window .This worked for me.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>READ JSON Example (AJAX)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $.getJSON("http://www.bonar.si/api/restaurants.php", function(result){
          $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("#output").append("Name: "+ field.name + " address: "+field.address +" Price:"+field.price+"<br/>");
          });
          });
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something doesn't work because of a security feature. Solution: completely disable the security feature... O.o

Comment: it works if i disable security feature, but is it possible to do this the "right" way?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted server owner and he enabled CORS, so it's working now!